# use variable as a column name in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Is there any to use variable names as a column name in sql join, without using dynamic query?

I want to use it like below.

`DECLARE @PT_CONST VARCHAR(MAX)`

`SELECT * FROM TBL T WHERE T.@PT_CONST='VAL'`

Comment: you can do like this if you can SELECT * FROM TBL T WHERE coulmn_nmae = @PT_CONST

Answer (score 1):

Directly not. If you know that your column name can be one of the predefined set, then you could use something like

```
... WHERE CASE @PT_CONST WHEN 'Col1' THEN Col1 WHEN 'Col2' THEN Col2 ... END = 'VAL'
```

Comment: dont know the column names..so your solution is not feasible

Comment: Then you have no solution without dynamic SQL. SQL server query processor needs to know column names at compile time, there is no way around it. You could check presence of columns before building your dynamic SQL to avoid errors of course.